# Bluetooth not found ( RealTek RT3290LE ) but worked in Windows

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, hp

I installed Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS on an [HP Probook 4440s](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03356342), replacing Windows 10.

It shows that *No Bluetooth is found. Please connect a Dongle to use.* But I clearly remember connecting my phone, speakers and headphones to my device, when using Win 10. I have searched around on the forum, but haven't got an exact or definite answer. Plus, i am not sure on whether to take the mentioned steps as it might adversely affect the device.

Here's the result when i ran `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

```
~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
    Kernel modules: rt2800pci
--
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [103c:17f3]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b370 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:003d Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS491
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    0.118274] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.157257] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[   45.252499] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Loading firmware file 'rt3290.bin'
[   45.293858] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Firmware detected - version: 0.37
[  239.211492] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[  239.211560] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[  239.211565] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[  239.211567] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[  239.211572] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[  261.115924] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[  261.115927] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[  261.115936] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

I am new to Linux and mostly a code noob. So I might not understand few things, so please bear with me.

What's going on and how to deal with it?